# Django:Unable to compare the logged in user with the author of the post

Tags: python, django

I am building a django blogging website .I want to compare the current logged in user with the author of the blog-post and if they are same ,then allow them the edit functionality but my code is not executing the if statement even if they both are same.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.username == post.author %}
```

Models-

```
class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
         default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(
         blank=True, null=True)

   def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

   def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: can you print `post.author`?

Comment: Yes,I am able to print post.author

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking against the `username`, you should be checking against the user object itself.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the `username` and the `User` instance in your code.  Update the condition to something like this:

`{% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}`

or

`{% if user.is_authenticated and user.username == post.author.username %}`